# Make 2 rows of information distinguishable in print view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing, colors

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but:

I'm working on pulling some tabular data out for a client using bootstrap's striped table.

[image]

In print view I'd like to make these rows distinguishable (as seen above), yet not chew through the ink as lots of these will be printed on a daily basis and distributed so being efficient is important. I'm open to suggestions, websites that can help with choosing printer friendly colours or anything really.

Comment: What does "distinguishable" mean to you?

Comment: Are you using a separate stylesheet for printing? And you should post your code to a Snippet.

Comment: code really doesn't have a play as it's all working as expected. What I'm looking for are print friendly colours. printing a row ALL grey uses much more ink than necessary. I'd like an alternative like bolding an entire row or something to make each row stand out

Comment: While not able to calculate ink densities and usage and price for one color vs. another, I would guess the least expensive would be alternating italic and normal. Another would be bold and not bold. Of course, *none* of us know whether you bold or italicize words in those other rows. So how are we to know?